# Stuck: onclick background color attribute changing correctly but actual color not displaying (with PHP loop)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a favorite button that selects the current color displayed and this color is then injected into a favorites bar. I added a PHP loop to select different colors and add them next to the last selected favorite. The background attribute is changing but for some reason, it isn't showing the color.

JavaScript:

```
    $('#fav-colour-pallete-' + id).click(function getFav() { //Button
      var favColor = $('#colour-pallete-' + id).attr('color-hex');
            $('.fav-color-' + id).css('background', '#' + favColor);
                  $('.fav-color-' + id).attr('color-hex', favColor)
      });

 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 favorites">
        <p class="h6 favorites-title mb-0 mt-2">Favorites:</p>
           <ul class="list-inline favorites-list mb-0">
              <?php for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++) { ?>
                 <li class="list-inline-item fav-color-<?php echo $i; ? 
                     >"></li>
<button id="fav-colour-pallete-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="fav- 
        colour-pallete b  tn btn-secondary palette-btn" type="button">
          <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
        </button>
              <?php } ?>
          </ul>
 </div>
```

If I remove the loop from the HTML and the ID from fav-color in JavaScript it does display/add the color to the favorites bar but replaces the last favorite.

I believe the issue has something to do with the loop. And it's so strange that I can see the background attribute changing correctly in the console but the color doesn't actually change.

Comment: Shouldn't `css('background', '#' + favColor)` be `css('background-color', '#' + favColor)`?

Comment: Perhaps but it is working without the php loop and the background attribute is being added as a style with the php loop, just not displaying

Comment: Added button to code

Comment: @msg ok will update in 30 mins

Comment: @msg have updated

Answer (score 0):

Where is the #id you are targeting in the script?
It is not from the PHP loop. It is a targeting error of your script. Try pasting the

manually and you will have the same problem. (Don't forget to change the indexes of  fav-color :)

Comment: What do you mean by “the •” . ID is a js variable that increments .fav-color- (1-6) it is also ref the ID of the color that is selected. Sorry what do you mean by index?

Answer (score 0):

There's some code missing, but my guess is that you are setting up the `click()` handlers using something like this:

```
for (var id = 1; id < 10; id++) {
  $('#fav-' + id).click()
}
```

By the time that the handler gets executed, the loop has finished and the global variable `id` has value 9 (your last element).

To demonstrate:

HTML:

```
<div id="fav-1">Element 1</div>
<div id="fav-2">Element 2</div>
<div id="fav-3">Element 3</div>
```

JS:

```
for (var id = 1; id <=3; id++) {
  console.log("Adding handler for " + id);
  $("#fav-" + id).click(function() {
    console.log("clicked on #" + this.id)
    console.log("variable value: " + id);
    // This variable doesn't match the selector!    
  });
}
```

Sorry, but your example is way too complicated and apparently I completely misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Sorry @msg could you please elaborate (3 month old coder) - If the attributes are being added then the loop is working surely?

Comment: Yeah I did add the minimal code originally, nothing more was needed as ID etc irrelevant. But you wanted the button and click events and more code (when it’s thousands of lines) and I also said it works, it just does not actually display the color. The attribute is there, click event works. I don’t really understand your example, but I really do appreciate you spending the time to help me figure it out.

Comment: no I added that as “showing my work” and  proving that the code does work without the loop and actually shows the color. And then I said with the loop, it adds the attributes correctly but the actual color doesn’t display. I also mentioned that I believed it had something to do with the loop because of this. Please could you elaborate on the rebind? I have only managed to get it to work by adding the code to the changeColor function - which I think is what you are talking about? Feel like I’m not understanding a fundamental rule here

Comment: @LexRidley yes, that's exactly what I mean. Once you bind the click event to an element, it shouldn't be necessary to do it again. Could you try this bit of [js](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/796243/)? It's a bit ugly, but sidesteps the problem and works for me in your site...